# Compare the z-scores of two groups

Tags: z-score

I have z-scores of 2 groups and I want to compare the groups. What would be the best way to compare these groups? Since both groups have the same mean and standard deviations, I think it is not appropriate to use the t-test.

What is the best way to compare these groups?